# jquery hover function not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, css

I have no idea why this little bit of jquery won't work with my code -- here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".dl").hover(function (u) {
        $(".pdf:hover").show();
    },
    function (u) {
        $(".pdf:hover").hide();
    });
});
```

It should make it so that when I hover over .dl :

```
.dl {
    font-size: .6em;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -78px 0 0 63%;
    text-align: left;
}

.dl a, a:active, a:visited {
    color: #fff; 
}

.dl a:hover {
    color: #33b5e5;
}
```

.pdf:hover shows, no?

```
.pdf {
    background: url("images/ref_button.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    max-height: 115px;
    width: 101px;
    max-width: 101px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -120px 0 0 45%;
    display: block;
}

.pdf:hover {
    background: url("images/ref_button_hover.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    max-height: 115px;
    width: 101px;
    max-width: 101px;
    display: block;
}
```

The hover works fine normally, it's just the jquery bit that won't work. Any suggestions? The only thing I can think of is that the :hover on the .pdf class is what's breaking it, but I tried it with an entirely separate .pdfhover class and it still didn't work, so maybe not... gah!

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You have already cal hover event no need to write `$(".pdf:hover")` only write `$(".pdf")`
Thats it!

Comment: Ahh Sudhir said the same thing, but my problem is a little different.. .pdf has an image on it and when I hover over .pdf another image (in .pdf:hover) appears. I just need it so when I hover over .dl (which is just some text) .pdf:hover appears! thanks for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$(".pdf:hover").show();
```

to

```
$(".pdf").show(); //similar change for hide() too
```

**Update**
You can make a class `pdfhover` for hover in pdf, like,

```
.pdfhover {
    background: url("images/ref_button_hover.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    max-height: 115px;
    width: 101px;
    max-width: 101px;
    display: block;
}
```

and do,

```
$(".dl").hover(function (u) {
        $(".pdf").addClass("pdfhover");
    },
    function (u) {
        $(".pdf").removeClass("pdfhover");
    });
```

Comment: Ahh sorry, i should have put the original .pdf code in the main post, I'll edit it now -- this just makes the original image disappear when I'm not hovering over .dl. I need the image from .pdf:hover to appear over the original .pdf image when I hover on .dl! thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: I tried this, and now when I hover over .pdf nothing happens and when I hover over .dl .pdfhover does not appear :(

Comment: @shanling have you created .pdfhover class in css not .pdf:hover..?

Comment: i tried adding z-index to both of them also because I thought that maybe .pdf was still showing up above .pdfhover but no luck

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30966/discussion-between-sudhir-and-shanling)

Comment: @shanling it seems more like a css issue rather than js issue

Answer (score 0):

Its the negative margin that messes...remove those and it works. Fiddle was in pure JS...also make sure JQuery Library is referred.